# How to get the current record in the database

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I have a database with the following record:
timer_id = 1
time = 498

I'm retrieving the record in the time column but it won't retrieve the current record. I have this code for retrieving it:

```
<script>
  function start(){
    div = "<?php $select = mysql_query('SELECT COUNT(*) AS num FROM tbl_timer',$connection); while($row = mysql_fetch_array($select)){ $num = $row['num']; } ?>";
    var num = "<?php echo $num; ?>";
    alert(num);
     if(num == 0)
     {
       document.getElementById("form1").innerHTML = '<input id="time1" onChange="alert(\'Hallo\')" value="720"/>'; 

     }
     if(num !== '0')
     {
       var div = "<?php $select = mysql_query('SELECT COUNT(*) AS nu FROM tbl_timer',$connection); while($row = mysql_fetch_array($select)){ $nu = $row['nu']; } if($nu !== '0'){$select = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM tbl_timer',$connection); while($row = mysql_fetch_array($select)){ $time = $row['time']; $tc = $row['utc']; }}else{$time = 0; $tc= 0;} ?>";
       var time = "<?php echo $time; ?>";
       alert(time);

       document.getElementById("form1").innerHTML = '<input id="time" value="'+time+'"/>'; 
       document.getElementById("h").innerHTML = ' <button id="pt" onclick="pause()">Pause</button>';

    secondPassed();    
     }
  }
</script>
```

Whenever I alert the 'time' the output will be the previous record that was 510.
What will I do to get the current record every time it will be stored in the database.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as a 'current record', at least not in the way you are using it. Once you start your second query, the database starts all over at the beginning of the table. Also, there's no guarantuee that the order in which the rows are returned are the same.

I'm not sure what you are trying to do, but I suggest you read some tutorials on using WHERE clauses, ORDER BY, etc.